# processing resizing shapes while zooming in

Tags: 3d, resize, processing

I'm having trouble re-sizing the sphere when zooming in so that it gets smaller along with the box and the collision boundaries also resize as the box gets smaller. What am I doing wrong? This is my code:

```
float rotX, rotY;
float zoom = 1;
float angle = 0;
float bounds = 500;
int amount = 8000;
MovingSphere s;
int[] x = new int[amount];
int[] y = new int[amount];
int[] z = new int[amount];

void setup() {
  size(900, 900, P3D);
  background(0);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(1);
  s = new MovingSphere();
  for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
    x[i] = int(random(-250, 250));
    y[i] = int(random(-250, 250));
    z[i] = int(random(-250, 250));
  }
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  lights();
  pushMatrix();
  //translations();
  //scale (zoom);
  //rotate (angle);
  s.collisions();
  s.location();
  s.display();
  popMatrix();
  translations();
  scale (zoom);
  rotate (angle);
  //s.collisions();
  //s.location();
  //s.display();
  box(bounds);
  for(int i = 0; i<amount; i++) {
    point(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
  }
}

void mouseDragged(){
  float x1 = mouseX-pmouseX;
  float y1 = mouseY-pmouseY;
  rotX += -y1 * 0.01;
  rotY += x1 * 0.01;

}

void translations() {
  rotateX(rotX);
  rotateY(rotY);
}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent event){
  float e = event.getCount();
  zoom += e *.01;
  println(e);
}
```

Second file:

```
float xpos = 200;
float ypos = 50;

float gravity = 0.98;
float bounce = -1;

class MovingSphere {
 PVector position;
 PVector velocity;
 MovingSphere(){
   position = new PVector(0, 0, 0);
   velocity = new PVector(2.5, 5, 7.5);
   //vy = new PVector(0, 0, 0);

   }

   void location() {
     position.add(velocity);

     translate(position.x, position.y, position.z);
   }
   void collisions(){
     if (position.x > bounds/2.7 || position.x < -bounds/2.7) {
       velocity.x*=-1;
     }
     if (position.y > bounds/2.7 || position.y < -bounds/2.7) {
       velocity.y*=-1;
     }
     if (position.z > bounds/2.7 || position.z < -bounds/2.7) {
       velocity.z*=-1;
     }
   }

  void display() {
    //stroke(255);
    //fill(50, 70, 230);
    sphere(30);
  }
}
```

Comment: What trouble are you having? What does this code do? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: The code works so that the sphere will bounce off of the boundaries of the box. You can zoom in or zoom out or rotate the box. However, when you do this, the box boundaries don't change when I rotate the box or zoom in. I'm trying to figure out how to fix that.